# How to release an object from a completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have an object with a method which receives a completion handler.

In the completion handler, I would like to release this object (assign nil, using ARC).

But completion handler is called from the scope of the caller (the object to be released) so it is not released.

For instance

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void)doSomeWork
{
  self.objectToRelease someLongRunningMethod:^{
    // did complete
    // [self finish]; // maybe should be "weak self"
 }
}

-(void)finish
{
// clean up of this object
  self.objectToRelease = nil; // not released
}

@end
```

Comment: `objectToRelease` _will_ be released when assigning nil. However, that does not mean it will be deallocated. It will be deallocated only if there is no other strong reference to that object. You may check if there is possibly another object holding a strong reference to it - or if there is possibly a cyclic reference elsewhere.

Comment: It would probably be better to not have `objectToRelease` as a property / instance variable of `self` at all; and instead pass it to `finish:` inside the block from `doSomeWork`.